# System.Threading.ExecutionContext doesn't implement interface System.IDisposable

Tags: c#, mono, task, dataflow

In our application we are currently moving to `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` to manage all communications. But now each time we use our Network Client/Server classes in any custom `SynchronizationContext` we get an exception.

> *"System.Threading.ExecutionContext doesn't implement interface
>   System.IDisposable".*

I don't see how this is even possible. We never change or play with any threads execution contexts. The closest to it that we do is

```
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext (new GtkSynchronizationContext ());
    Scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ();
    Factory = new TaskFactory (Scheduler);
```

I don't see why a custom `SynchronizationContext` would make DataFlow crash like this.
What follows is the output of the application leading to the DataFlow exception.

```
madrang@Qosmio-X770:~$ '/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/runbuild' 
Engine Initialize started
==============================================================================
Application Information
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Program      : /home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/Bin/Linsft.Engine.dll
Time         : 14/04/2013 04:46:02
User         : madrang
Computer     : Qosmio-X770
OS           : Linux64
Processors   : 8
Working Set  : 0
Framework    : 4.0.30319.1
Run Time     : 00:00:01.6015700
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded Modules
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/mono||0
/usr/bin/mono||3031040
/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll|4.0.0.0|188416
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Runtime.Serialization/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll|3.0.0.0|196608
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll|3.0.0.0|1396736
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll|4.0.0.0|1748992
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll|4.0.0.0|1273856
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll|4.0.0.0|798720
/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/Bin/NLog.dll|2.0.0.0|319488
/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/Bin/Mono.Addins.dll|1.0.0.0|237568
/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/Bin/Mono.Addins.Setup.dll|1.0.0.0|131072
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.17.so||49152
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.17.so||45056
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.17.so||94208
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.17.so||32768
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll|4.0.0.0|2867200
/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive||2920448
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so||1826816
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.17.so||98304
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so||12288
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.17.so||28672
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so||1060864
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so||143360
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll|4.0.0.0|126976
/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/Bin/Linsft.Engine.dll|0.5.4849.6350|36864
/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/Invensys.exe|1.0.4845.22748|8192
/run/shm/mono.8910||4096
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded Assembly
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mono.Posix, 4.0.0.0
System.Runtime.Serialization, 3.0.0.0
System.ServiceModel, 3.0.0.0
System, 4.0.0.0
System.Configuration, 4.0.0.0
System.Xml, 4.0.0.0
System.Core, 4.0.0.0
NLog, 2.0.0.0
Mono.Addins, 1.0.0.0
Mono.Addins.Setup, 1.0.0.0
Linsft.Engine, 0.5.4849.6350
Invensys, 1.0.4845.22748
mscorlib, 4.0.0.0
==============================================================================
Registed new scheduler: ThreadPool
Addin Loaded: Linsft.Engine
Assembly Loaded ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, 2.84.0.0
Assembly Loaded Mono.Addins.CecilReflector, 1.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded Mono.CSharp, 4.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded NLog.Extended, 2.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded xunit, 1.9.1.1600
Assembly Loaded xunit.extensions, 1.9.1.1600
Assembly Loaded xunit.runner.utility, 1.9.1.1600
Addin Loaded: Linsft.Invensys
Starting new task in default scheduler: Linsft.CommandExtensionNode: Id=Linsft.Core.IdleScheduler.Initialize, Linsft.Core.IdleScheduler.Initialize()
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Core, 1.0.4850.6090
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Configuration, 0.0.0.1
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Network, 0.0.0.1
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Storage, 0.0.0.1
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Validator.Base, 1.0.0.22749
Assembly Loaded System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, 0.0.4303.21337
Assembly Loaded Ionic.Zip.Reduced, 1.9.1.8
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Helper, 1.0.4845.22748
Addin Loaded: Linsft.Core
Idle Scheduler Initialize
Idle Scheduler Started
Registed new scheduler: Idle
Starting pending task for: Idle
Scheduler Idle loaded, unlock Initialize
Assembly Loaded Mono.Security, 4.0.0.0
Starting new task in default scheduler: Linsft.CommandExtensionNode: Id=Linsft.Core.Gui.InitializeGtk, Linsft.Core.Gui.GtkScheduler.Initialize()
Addin Loaded: Linsft.Core.Gui
Assembly Loaded atk-sharp, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded cairo-sharp, 1.10.0.0
Assembly Loaded gdk-sharp, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded gio-sharp, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded glib-sharp, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded gtk-dotnet, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded gtk-sharp, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded pango-sharp, 3.0.0.0
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Core.Gui, 1.0.4850.6091
Gtk Scheduler Initialize
Scheduler not loaded, Will be started later: Linsft.CommandExtensionNode: Id=Linsft.Core.Gui.ShowMainWindow, Scheduler=Gtk, Linsft.Core.Gui.MainWindow.ShowWindow()
Gtk Scheduler Started
Starting new task in default scheduler: Linsft.CommandExtensionNode: Id=Linsft.Commander.Initialize, Linsft.Commander.Terminal.Initialize()
Addin Loaded: Linsft.Commander
Assembly Loaded Linsft.Commander, 1.0.4852.8576
Telnet server started: [ServicePoint: Address=tcp://127.0.0.1:8090/, ConnectionName=tcp, ConnectTimeout=15000, Port=8090]
Registed new scheduler: Gtk
Starting pending task for: Gtk
Building ExtendedWindow
Completed Building ExtendedWindow
Building MainWindow
Linsft.Core Opening Configuration Storage
Opening Container, Class=Linsft.Core.Configuration, Method=.cctor
Linsft.Core Configuration Loaded Sucessfully
MainWindow Width=800, Height=600
MainWindow X=65, Y=24
Completed Building MainWindow
Engine Initialize completed
TcpConnectionListener Connection Request: [ServicePoint: Address=tcp://127.0.0.1:8090/, ConnectionName=tcp, ConnectTimeout=15000, Port=8090]
Telnet client connected: [ServicePoint: Address=tcp://127.0.0.1:43544/, ConnectionName=tcp, ConnectTimeout=15000, Port=43544]
TcpConnectionListener received a new connection: [ServicePoint: Address=tcp://127.0.0.1:43544/, ConnectionName=tcp, ConnectTimeout=15000, Port=43544]
System.Threading.ExecutionContext doesn't implement interface System.IDisposable

Stacktrace:

  at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.Common.CreateCopyAndRun (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <0x00071>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.Common.InvokeCallbackWithContext (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) <0x0003b>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.TargetCore`1.ProcessMessagesLoopWithExecutionContext () <0x0011f>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.TargetCore`1.<ProcessAsyncIfNecessary_Slow>b__3 (object) <0x00033>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker/ActionObjectInvoke.Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task,object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task) <0x00023>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () <0x0005c>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () <0x001cf>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x0000f>
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TpScheduler.TaskExecuterCallback (object) <0x0004b>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    mono() [0x4961e9]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfbd0) [0x7fbd34914bd0]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7fbd34574037]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7fbd34577698]
    mono() [0x5cdd7f]
    mono() [0x5cde02]
    mono() [0x497eaf]
    mono() [0x4985c4]
    [0x41751bba]

Debug info from gdb:

Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

/home/madrang/WorkSpace/linsft/Source/Invensys/Build/invensys: line 5:  8910 Aborted                 (core dumped) mono "$INVENSYSDIR/Invensys.exe"
```

Running on Mono

```
madrang@Qosmio-X770:~$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Any idea is welcome, as I'm now starting my second week of reading docs and code trying to find a solution to this.

Thanks, Madrang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that somehow you are referencing a version of ExecutionContext that is pre-.NET 4.0.  You'll notice that prior to .NET 4.0, ExecutionContext doesn't implement IDisposable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext(v=vs.90).aspx

Above it shows you as using .NET 4.0, but is there anyway you can think of as to how you'd have an old version of `ExecutionContext` introduced in your application?  Are you by any chance using the .NET 3.5 backported System.Threading.dll? for Reactive Extensions?

I'm not a mono user, but does Mono's `ExecutionContext` implement `IDisposable` for .NET 4.0 (where would 
I check that)?  Looking at this:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/ExecutionContext.cs

it shows that it does, but I don't know if the current version of mono you are using has that code.

Comment: Right, it was not implemented in mono 2.10.8.1 Thanks now i also know why using mono 3 fixes it.

Comment: Excellent, glad you're back in business.

Answer (score 2):

Should have waited.... One of my coworker found a very simple fix.

```
madrang@Qosmio-X770:~$ /opt/mono-3/bin/mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.7 (tarball Sat Mar 30 14:45:04 UTC 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Now running under mono 3 and it works fine. It seams to be a bug with the latest mono 2 release.